# Counter() and string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

The issue can be solved in many ways but this question is about polymorphism. Is it possible to polymorph Counter() class so when there is no such key in Counter() instance string formatting would return 0? Basically is needed to make the last line of the code to work.

```
from collections import Counter
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
context = 'Computing is cool'
cnt = Counter()
for letter in context:
    if letter in VOWELS:
        cnt[letter] += 1    
print('o-{o}, i-{i}, o-{o}'.format(**cnt))

# I'd like to make this line to work :
#print('a-{a}, e-{e}, i-{i}, o-{o}, u-{u}'.format(**cnt))
```

Output:

```
o-3, i-2, u-1
```

Desirable output:

```
a-0, e-0, i-2, o-3, u-1
```

Comment: have you tried uncommenting the last line? because it works as you expect...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre last commented line doesn't work. It would return "KeyError: 'a'"

Comment: not for me it doesn't. But have you tried replacing `Counter` by `defaultdict(int)` ? _that_ would work.

Comment: replace "cnt = Counter()" with "cnt = dict()"? Then loop will fail.

Comment: not dict, `collections.defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a case for changing the `Counter`. `**` unpacking converts your `Counter` to a regular dict, which does not have a default value of 0 for missing keys. (At least, it converts your `Counter` now; [there was a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue18531) on earlier versions, so if you try the `**` code on an earlier Python version and it seems to work, that's why.)

Instead of `**`, use [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map), which will use your `Counter` directly:

```
print('o-{o}, i-{i}, o-{o}'.format_map(cnt))
```

Comment: note that it works as OP stated in version 3.4 of python. Maybe worth mentionning with the issue you linked to in comments

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Answer expanded.

Comment: that's a very good answer. I wish I could upvote once more for the `format_map` function only.

Answer (score 1):

> when there is no such key in `Counter()` instance string formatting would return 0?

but that's not the issue here. The issue is that `**cnt` will only unpack the existing elements.

What you can do is initialize the counter with zero counts for all `VOWELS` and then unpack:

```
cnt = Counter({i:0 for i in 'aeiou'})
```

now the unpacking will pick these elements up, even if they have a `0` count. After the loop executes, `print`:

```
print('a-{a}, e-{e}, i-{i}, o-{o}, u-{u}'.format(**cnt))
```

will return your wanted result:

```
a-0, e-0, i-2, o-3, u-1
```

Comment: `print('a-{a}, e-{e}, i-{i}, o-{o}, u-{u}'.format(**cnt))` works for me: I get `a-0, e-0, i-2, o-3, u-1` without setting anything to 0. At least in python 3.4 it works.

Comment: it does @Jean-FrançoisFabre? version? I can repro OPs KeyError with `3.6.3`

Comment: @jim-fasarakis-hilliard "The issue is that **cnt will only unpack the existing elements". Thanks, that's must be the case! But what does "i:0" do? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: [That was a bug.](https://bugs.python.org/issue18531)